# Akka-testkit "future.isCompleted" check

Tags: java, testing, akka

In this example:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/testing.html

```
final Props props = Props.create(MyActor.class);
final TestActorRef<MyActor> ref = TestActorRef.create(system, props, "testB");
final Future<Object> future = akka.pattern.Patterns.ask(ref, "say42", 3000);
assertTrue(future.isCompleted());
assertEquals(42, Await.result(future, Duration.Zero()));
```

What does: `assertTrue(future.isCompleted());` check? What is the way to make it return `false`?

**EDIT:**

I found the way how to make `isCompleted()` `false`. I've got `false` when in actor class I have nothing to return/`tell` back

(but it seems strange to me. it seems kind of validation.. ability actor to return back something for particular type of message **?** ):

```
if( message instanceof PutConfigurationMessage) {

        PutConfigurationMessage putConfigurationMessage = (PutConfigurationMessage) message;

        initSomeConfigurations(putConfigurationMessage.getConfigurations());

        // here might be this line:  `getSender().tell(resultMessage, getSelf());`

}
```

**The question now:** What I should do If I do not want to return/tell anything back? Kind of "all right". No exception then no problem ? or ??

Comment: Don't use "?" if you don't want to send anything back. use "!".

Answer (score 1):

That code looked wrong to me at first.  Usually, a future is computed on another thread and is `completed` when that other thread has finished computing the result.  So it looks quite wrong to assert that the future `isCompleted` right after the future is launched, without waiting for it to complete.

But what they explain in the doc you linked to is that when using `TestActorRef`, the future is computed on the *same* thread.  So the future is computed when `Pattern.ask()` is called and only after everything has run for that computation does it go to the next line, `assert(future.isCompleted)`.   It is true when using `TestActorRef`, but it would not be true in a real program.

They remove the concurrency/multithreading for testing since testing multithreaded code is nearly impossible due to its non-deterministic nature.

Answer (score 0):

It asserts that future.isComplete() returned a "true".  If would fail if it returns "false".

Answer (score 0):

Testing Akka-Actors using TestActorRef is completely different than using ActorRef:

- **TestActorRef** should be used for **Synchronous** testing
- **ActorRef** should be used for **Integration** testing

When declaring TestActorRef the running thread of the actor will be a single thread which runs synchronously and process the whole ActorSystem synchronously on the **same thread** as your test/console runs.

Quoting 2 important paragraph from the [article](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/testing.html) you mentioned:

> Messages sent to the actor are processed synchronously on the current thread and answers may be sent back as usual.
>
> ...
>
> TestActorRef overwrites two fields: it sets the dispatcher to CallingThreadDispatcher.global and it sets the receiveTimeout to None.

**I Found an answer for your new question**:

You should wait awhile before checking `future.isCompleted()`.
My code looks like this now (pay attention to the 4th line):

```
final Props props = Props.create(MyActor.class);
final TestActorRef<MyActor> ref = TestActorRef.create(system, props, "testB");
final Future<Object> future = akka.pattern.Patterns.ask(ref, "say42", 3000);
Await.ready(future, scala.concurrent.duration.Duration.Inf());
// Following assert should be true by now
assertTrue(future.isCompleted());
assertEquals(42, Await.result(future, Duration.Zero()));
```

Its ok to not returning/telling anything back. The ActorModel is suggesting that you if theres any error or problems in the actors work, than you should "tell" error message to a [supervisor actor](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/supervision.html) using "[Fault Tolerance](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/fault-tolerance.html)".
<s>You could not use isCompleted of Future if you don't return/tell anything back. Consider using a supervisor actor to handle results of actors and test him.</s>